# Why must the spring forces of springs in series be equal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring

I was learning about two springs in series connected to a wall on one side, and a block of mass m on the other.

Model:

WALL -- Spring 1 -- Spring 2 -- mass

They say that the force on the mass, $F_m = -k_2x_2 = F_2$, and the force on spring 2 is $F_1 = -k_1x_1$.

They also say that $F_1 = F_2 = F_m $.
But what I don't understand is that how come Newton's third law isn't being accounted for. Wouldn't the spring force of the spring on the mass also correspond to an equal but opposite force on the spring of $k_2x_2$, and the total force on spring 2: $k_2x_2 - k_1x_1 = 0$, so there is no net force on the spring?!

Overall, I don't know where they got the result or how they got the result that
$F_1 = F_2 = F_m $

Comment: Could it be that the problem is assuming that the springs are massless - and therefore must have a net force of 0?

Comment: Yes: your comment is correct.  It is common to use the massless spring approximation, which is reasonably good in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Springs in series in equilibrium experience the same tension (force) throughout while the displacements (the amount each stretches) depends upon the individual spring constants. This is necessary in order to satisfy both Newton’s 2nd and 3rd laws.

See the free body diagrams below showing the Newton 3rd law pairs and that the net force acting on the spring-mass system by the wall and external force on the mass system is zero satisfying Newton’s 2nd law for equilibrium.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Bob D, that's a good explanation and a really nice diagram, deserving of the upvote that I gave it.

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks for that

Comment: Wait, doesn't this assume that the springs are massless? And what if the springs are not in equilibrium but moving?

Comment: @EmilSriram yes it assumes the springs are massless since you provided no info on mass. And yes equilibrium is assumed since you said the system is attached to a wall and said nothing about harmonic motion. If you wished to include those things post a different question

Comment: Alright. Seems a bit passive aggressive, but okay. But seriously, greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: @EmilSriram, it assumes either massless or stationary springs.   In either situation the forces will be equal throughout the spring.  Accelerating massive springs have unequal forces.

Comment: @EmilSriram sorry. Didn’t mean to come off that way too

Comment: @BobD I don't understand, why must the force between spring 1 and 2 equal the weight of the mass M?

Comment: @FlinnBella where did I say anything about the weight of the mass?

Comment: @BobD isn't that F_m? I don't get why all the spring forces between have to equal Fm.  Won't the force change since the springs are oscillating?

Comment: @FlinnBella  First of all, $F_{M}$ is an external horizontal force applied to the mass. It is not the weight of the mass. Second, if you look at the comments between the OP you'll see I am  assuming massless springs and the springs and mass in equilibrium, not oscillating.

Comment: @BobD But springs must oscillate if force is applied to perform simple harmonic motion? How can springs and mass not be oscillating?

Comment: @FlinnBella as I’ve already stated   the configuration in the diagram is in equilibrium. Therefore no oscillation is involved.

Answer (score 1):

The mass exerts a force on spring 2, the modulus of which is equal to
\begin{equation}
F_m=k_2x_2
\end{equation}
The spring 2, on the other hand, exerts a force on the spring 1 uqual to
\begin{equation}
F_{2\rightarrow 1}=k_1x_1
\end{equation}
Meanwhile, the spring 1 exerts a force on the spring 2:
\begin{equation}
F_{1\rightarrow 2}=k_2x_2
\end{equation}
However, for the third principle these two forces must be equal. So you get the result.

Comment: this makes no sense. why does the third statement work?

Comment: The third law of dynamics is a first principle. We know from experience that, if a body (like spring 1) applies a force on a second body (like spring 2), then the second body applies a force equal and opposite to the first body, without exceptions.
I hope this answer your doubt

Comment: No but why does the spring 1 apply k2x2 force on spring 1. I thought that the spring 2 applies that to the mass?

Comment: Ah I think I understood now. According to your picture, the spring 2 applies a force from right to left to the mass, and also a force from left to right to the spring 1; this last force is k1x1. The spring 1, instead, applies only a force from right to left to the spring 2